# Elegant way of finding some maximum of an $n^{th}$ degree polynomial given a domain?

Tags: polynomials

I just ran into a polynomial of the form:$$1+x\left(p_{n \choose 1}\right)+x^2\left(p_{n \choose 2}\right)+x^3\left(p_{n \choose 3}\right) + ... + x^n\left(p_{n \choose n}\right)$$
where I'm and defining $p_{n \choose i}$ to be the sum over all the different products of combinations of p's (i.e when $i=2$ we have $p_1p_2+p_1p_3+...+p_1p_n+p_2p_3+...+p_2p_n+...+p_{n-1}p_n$).

Seeing this got me thinking, can we find some closed form for the maximum of a polynomial in some domain? If so when?

I know that in general this is not possible. But suppose, like in my case above, we knew $x \in (-1,1)$ and $p \in (-1,1)$, it seems like we can start saying plenty about bounds of each term in every order of derivative. Anyhow, sorry for rambling, I plan on digging into this more carefully when I have more time but was wondering if I was just missing something trivial.

tl;dr: Can we find some closed form for the maximum of a polynomial in some domain? If so when?

Comment: It looks like you're writing $\prod (x+p_i)$ where $\sum p_i=1$.  Is this where your polynomial came from?

Comment: It actually came from $\prod (1 + xp_i)$.